# SwiftUI ColorPicker Fails In Background (Menubar) App

Tags: macos, swiftui, appkit, color-picker, lsuielement

## Context

I have an app that runs only from the macOS menubar. (The `LSUIElement` property in `info.plist` is set to `YES`).

Instead of a menu, this app shows an `NSPopover` when the menubar button is clicked. The popover holds an `NSHostingView` which has an extremely simple SwiftUI view:

```
struct PopoverContentView: View
{
    @State private var color: CGColor = .white

    var body: some View
    {
        ColorPicker(selection: $color) {
            Text("Pick a Color:")
        }
    }
}
```

## Problem

Clicking on the `ColorPicker()` does not open the macOS color picker window. The UI of the `ColorPicker()` button changes, to show the "selected" border state but the color-picker window never appears.

However, if I change `LSUIElement` to be `NO` **and** then make the app active by clicking its Dock icon (so that it takes over the menubar), **THEN** clicking on the `ColorPicker()` in the popover actually reveals the color-picker window.

Do you know of a way to force macOS to show the color-picker window for a background application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be simple. In the AppKit ViewController that opens the popover when the menubar button is clicked (`PopoverController`, for me), I simply did this:

```
extension PopoverController: NSPopoverDelegate
{
    func popoverWillShow(_ notification: Notification)
    {
        NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    }
}
```

The `ColorPicker` now correctly shows the standard macOS system color panel on click.